# Service won't come up when using static IP on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have allocated a static IP on my GCP account. Then, I updated my application's service definition to use this in a load balancer, like so:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  # Unique key of the Service instance
  name: my-app-service
spec:
  ports:
    # Accept traffic sent to port 80
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    # Loadbalance traffic across Pods matching
    # this label selector
    app: web
  # Create an HA proxy in the cloud provider
  # with an External IP address - *Only supported
  # by some cloud providers*
  type: LoadBalancer
  # Use the static IP allocated
  loadBalancerIP: 35.186.xxx.xxx
```

If I comment out the last line and let GKE allocate an ephemeral public IP, the service comes up just fine. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Based on advise in an answer, I created an `Ingress` as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "myapp"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-app-service
    servicePort: 80
```

Now, I see the `Ingress` getting assigned the right static IP. However, my `Service` also gets assigned a (different) public IP. The `Ingress` and `Service` are not connected. If I comment out the `type: LoadBalancer` line, the `Service` is not assigned a public IP, but `Ingress` still does not connect. I get a `default backend - 404` response when hitting the static IP. I have tried creating the service and ingress in different orders and that has not helped either.

If I leave this up long enough, the static IP routes traffic to my service, but the service itself stays stuck in external IP assignment:

```
$ kubectl get service my-app-service
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
my-app-service          10.x.x.x        <pending>     80:31432/TCP   12m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `Ingress` and use the `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "name-of-your-ip"` annotation on the Ingress for Kubernetes to be able to find it.

You can find a tutorial here: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/ingress-with-static-ip#tutorial

Comment: Thanks Ahmet. I created the ingress and I see it successfully link with the static IP. However, it does not seem to connect with my service. If I leave the line `type:LoadBalancer` in there, then my service gets assigned a different IP from the ingress. The service public IP hit my app and ingress returns a `404`. If I comment out `type:LoadBalancer`, then my service has no external IP and ingress is still on `404`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Raj, I'd recommend following the tutorial above from beginning to end and see if it works. If it does not we should probably open an issue to the repo and get it fixed. Eventually, the answer to your question should be the link I posted.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet. The tutorial exposes a `NodePort` service. I am trying a `LoadBalancer` service. I explicitly changed my YAML above to set `type: NodePort` and I still get a 404 when hitting the external IP. I have created this defect for now: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44521

Comment: I think the external IP finally sends traffic to my service whether its `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort`, except it takes a very long time to begin doing this, like 7-8 minutes. The static IP initially returns HTTP `404`, then `502` and finally after several minutes, I see my application. I am guessing this is a k8s/GKE bug

Comment: @Raj that's actually because Google Cloud is configuring the Load Balancer at all of its edge locations around the world and it takes time. GCP's load balancers are not regional and are able to accept traffic at edge locations all across the world, and then forward to your application through Google’s internal network. That's why `gce` ingress takes about 5 minutes to actually work. I was confused about myself, too.